# Logging Ehcache get requests

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, terracotta

I am trying to write a class that would trace all Ehcache GET requests. For the performance obsessed - this would only be switched on for debugging purposes.

I can see following three options available:

1) write an implementation of `net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener`. This would be my preferred way, but it only has PUT/REMOVE/etc. hooks. No GET. Doh!

2) write an implementation of `net.sf.ehcache.statistics.CacheUsageListener`. The problem with this approach is that this interface is more designed for statistics and does not even provide access to things like current cache key/element, so I would have to do horrible hacks (think: sharing state through `ThreadLocal`) to achieve what I want. Yuck!

3) write an Ehcache wrapper, and channel all requests through it. Quite painful as we use Ehcache in different ways (with Hibernate and without), meaning I would have to write different wrappers for all these different cases. Adds maintenance pains and isn't really precise as it is not possible to know, for example, if a GET operation has hit a stale entry or not.

Are there any other options I missed?

Answer (score 1):

A fourth option would be to enable debug level logging for net.sf.ehcache.Cache *and* enable cache statistics for the caches you want to trace the information.
You'd then get "Cache: " + getName() + " store hit for " + key" or "configuration.getName() + " cache hit, but element expired"" log statements... So for misses as well.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but unfortunately not good enough. The problem with this approach is that it would sometimes be hard (if not impossible) to connect two log lines with each other, especially if there are lots of other cache activity going on.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with connecting two lines together, what kind of log lines ? Having the thread id in there ? Or something else ?

Comment: If I follow your advice, I will be getting two log lines - one coming from net.sf.ehcache.Cache and another from cache statistics class. If there is lots of other caching activity, matching the two log lines can prove difficult. Correct me if I got your advice wrong.

Comment: I think if you look at [Cache's source](http://svn.terracotta.org/fisheye/browse/Ehcache/trunk/core/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.java?hb=true) you'll see that searchInStoreWithStats has the logging (I think) you want.